# feeding the output of wordexp to getopt_long crashes my linux cli application

Tags: c, linux, arguments, glib

I am trying to create a small linux command line application. 
One can run the application by passing arguments when calling the application , which I parse using getopt() .

One can choose to run this application in interactive mode, in which case a small menu is presented and the user should be able to enter similar options as the ones they add when running the application.

To avoid creating a different parser when I am in interactive mode, I wanted to parse the keyboard input to argc & argv and feed that in the same getopt() function.

The proof of concept `c` function I created is the following:

```
void menuDlg()
{
    char kbinput[256];
    wordexp_t we;
    char **argAr;
    int argCount = 0 ,i,er=0;

    printf("showing menu options\n");
    //...
    //...

    ///grab keyboard input
    fgets(kbinput,256,stdin);

    ///the "\n" in kbinput breaks we 
    ///and we.we_wordc return weird value, 
    ///so we need to remove it
    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        if (kbinput[i]=='\n')
        {
            kbinput[i]='\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("you typed |%s|\n",kbinput);

    we.we_offs = 0;
    if ( (er=wordexp(kbinput, &we, 0)) != 0)
    {
        printf("error in word expansion %d\n",er);
    }
    argAr = we.we_wordv;
    argCount = we.we_wordc;
    printf("we.c=%u\n",we.we_wordc);

    main_dialog( argCount, argAr );

    wordfree(&we);
}
```

were main_dialog() parses the cli options

```
void main_dialog( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    while ( (ch = getopt_long(argc, argv, "yscvh", longopts, NULL)) != -1 )
    switch (ch)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

But when I run this my application crashes inside the call to `getopt_long()`.

I read that `argv` is supposed to have a final entry of `null`. so for parameters "foo bar" , we'd have argc=2 , but argv[0]="foo" , argv[1]="bar" and argv[2]='\0' . In [wordexp documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html) it states little about the internal structure of we_wordv (that is about a tailing NULL array entry) so I do not know  if this is the problem.

Could this be the source of the problem? Is there another `glib` function to do what I need?

thank you

Comment: First of all, `getopt` and `getopt_long` expects that the actual arguments starts at `argv[1]`. Secondly, the terminating entry is `argv[argc]` which is a null-pointer, i.e. `NULL`, which `wordexp` adds for you.

Comment: Also, when the crash happens, what is the values of `argc` and the contents of `argv`?

Comment: Have you already used `getopt()` or `getopt_long()` before? If so, you probably need to reinitialize them so that they start at the beginning of your current argument list, rather than continuing with the original argument list. It is not always clear how to do that reset. BSD (Mac OS X) documents: _In order to use `getopt()` to evaluate multiple sets of arguments, or to evaluate a single set of arguments multiple times, the variable `optreset` must be set to 1 before the second and each additional set of calls to `getopt()`, and the variable `optind` must be reinitialized._ Others don't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bingo! Reading through the manual, it appears in linux to reset the getopt() subsystem one must pass `optind=0;` Still you put me in the right track. you may want to add this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer — and then expanding on the ideas.*</sup>

- Have you already used `getopt()` or `getopt_long()` before calling the code in `main_dialog()`? If so, you probably need to reinitialize them so that they start at the beginning of your current argument list, rather than continuing with the original argument list.

It is not always clear how to do that reset.

BSD (Mac OS X) documents:

> In order to use `getopt()` to evaluate multiple sets of arguments, or to evaluate a single set of arguments multiple times, the variable `optreset` must be set to 1 before the second and each additional set of calls to `getopt()`, and the variable `optind` must be reinitialized.

It also documents the extra variable: `extern int optreset;`

Other systems don't clearly document what needs to be done.  Note that the POSIX specification for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) specifically states (*emphasis* added):

> The variable `optind` is the index of the next element of the `argv[]` vector to be processed. It shall be initialized to 1 by the system, and `getopt()` shall update it when it finishes with each element of `argv[]`. *If the application sets `optind` to zero before calling `getopt()`, the behavior is unspecified.* When an element of `argv[]` contains multiple option characters, it is unspecified how `getopt()` determines which options have already been processed.

Therefore, you may need to experiment to find what works.

Judging from the [response comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862523/feeding-the-output-of-wordexp-to-getopt-long-crashes-my-linux-cli-application?noredirect=1#comment51670652_31862523), sometimes setting `optind = 0;` will work (that seems to be for Linux).  It is not clear that it will work everywhere (POSIX says it may not); test before using!

You could experiment with a program like this one, which I called `getopt-test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void dump_getopt_state(const char *tag)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    printf("optind = %d, ", optind);
    printf("opterr = %d, ", opterr);
    printf("optopt = %d, ", optopt);
    printf("optarg = %p\n", (void *)optarg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    dump_getopt_state("Initial");
    char tag[32];

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ab:cd:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'c':
            sprintf(tag, "Option %c", opt);
            break;
        case 'b':
        case 'd':
            sprintf(tag, "Option %c", opt);
            printf("Argument: %s\n", optarg);
            break;
        }
        dump_getopt_state(tag);
    }

    dump_getopt_state("Final");
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (Mac OS X 10.10.4):

```
$ getopt-test
Initial:
optind = 1, opterr = 1, optopt = 0, optarg = 0x0
Final:
optind = 1, opterr = 1, optopt = 0, optarg = 0x0
$ getopt-test -a
Initial:
optind = 1, opterr = 1, optopt = 0, optarg = 0x0
Option a:
optind = 2, opterr = 1, optopt = 97, optarg = 0x0
Final:
optind = 2, opterr = 1, optopt = 97, optarg = 0x0
$ getopt-test -ac
Initial:
optind = 1, opterr = 1, optopt = 0, optarg = 0x0
Option a:
optind = 1, opterr = 1, optopt = 97, optarg = 0x0
Option c:
optind = 2, opterr = 1, optopt = 99, optarg = 0x0
Final:
optind = 2, opterr = 1, optopt = 99, optarg = 0x0
$
```

Note the state after processing the `a` option of `-ac`.  The only visible change in state is in `optopt`, and it is likely that modifying `optopt` does not trigger the reset.  Setting `optind` to zero might do the trick, but the official value of `optind` at program startup is `1`.

This is also an object lesson in why global variables are bad.

Note also that it is not clear what will happen if you change the value(s) of `argc` and `argv` between calls to `getopt()`.  The specification does not say that the values shall be the same each time, but chaos is likely to reign if you don't reset the code to a starting point.

The output format of my code could be improved to print `optopt` as a 2-digit hex value.  It might be better if the `:` was passed as part of the tag to the dump function; then the first print could be: `printf("%-.12s ", tag)` so everything aligns.  The value of `optarg` is the one that's most likely to vary in length; that's why it is last.

Comment: Unlikely as it may be `optind = 0` is what the manual pages of linux suggest. See under "notes" section http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt

Comment: @nass: That's fine — it is a legitimate design decision that can be documented.  It isn't guaranteed to work on other systems, so you have to read the manual pages on each system, and hope that it is actually documented.